# FOSUSER Bundle with multiple USer + Inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I use PUGXMulti USer , it is An extension for FOSUserBundle to handle users of different types.
Following the documentation STep by Step , I created my Entity USER , and 2 other Entities ( Driver , Client ) extends User

```
/**@ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user_one" = "Dali/FrontBundle/Driver", "user_two" = "Dali/FrontBundle/Client"})
 *
 */
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id_user;
```

Client entity start with  :

```
* @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
*/
class Client extends User
{
    /**
     * @var string

     */
    private $fnameClient;
```

I created a FormType for ClientRegistration ,

```
class ClientFormType extends AbstractType {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fnameClient');
        $builder->add('username');
        $builder->add('email');
```

The problem is when I submit the form , it gave me the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.username AS username2, t1.username_canonical AS username_canonical3, .... FROM client t1 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ?' with params ["az"]:
```

My remarks is why he is trying to do `where t0.username_canonical` istead of t1.username_canonical

Comment: the query is for selecting user not inserting one so I suppose you have successfully registered a client and you get a problem showing it right ?

Comment: No , FOSUSerbbundle see if username exist in database before inserting

Comment: maybe you have a problem in your entities mapping, execute `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` to check if every thing is ok. also the sql query is not complete and i think the .... are hiding important information to know the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1166) :

> FOSUserBundle is not designed to work with entity inheritance (and you should probably avoid it as it is a performance killer for Doctrine as relational databases are bad at storing inheritance)